# How to transform array of hex into array of base10 integers?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

```
    local regex="s/rgb:\([^/]\+\)\/\([^/]\+\)\/\([^/]\+\)/\1 \2 \3/p"
    local colors=$(xtermcontrol --get-bg | sed -n $regex)
    local base10_colors=()
    for i in 1 2 3; do
        $base10_colors[i]=$((16#$colors[i]))
    done
```

I have this for now, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a variable with a hexadecimal number, such as 'FF00', and you want to convert it to decimal, then you may use `bc`:

```
hex='FF00'
dec=$( printf 'ibase=16; %s\n' "$hex" | bc )
```

Here, `bc` will output `65280` and the shell will store that as as string in the variable `dec`.

Setting the `ibase=16` tells `bc` that the input base is 16 (i.e. hexadecimal).  It also has an `obase` variable (output base) that one could use with `ibase` for arbitrary conversions.

If you have an array of hexadecimal values:

```
colors=( $(xtermcontrol --get-bg | sed -n $regex) )
typeset -a base10_colors
for hex in "${colors[@]}"; do
  base10_colors+=( "$( printf 'ibase=16; %s\n' "$hex" | bc )" )
done
```

Or, with that `zsh` syntax:

```
colors=( $(xtermcontrol --get-bg | sed -n $regex) )
typeset -a base10_colors
for hex in "${colors[@]}"; do
  base10_colors+=( $((16#$hex)) )
done
```

Comment: I know how to transform a value. But I don't know how to transform array.

Comment: @user1685095 One at a time. I have updated the answer.

Comment: the first one gives me `(standard_in) 1: syntax error` and the second one works